# ASP.NET MVC: Call method in another namespace / area

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this simple class inside my ASP.NET MVC 3 application:

```
namespace My.Project.Controllers
{
    public ActionResult Settings()
    {
        var m = GetUserData(userID);
        ...
    }

    private UserModel GetUserData(string id)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            return null;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, I have created a separate area inside the application to house an API. How do I call methods in the first namespace?

```
namespace My.Project.Areas.api.Controllers
{
    public ActionResult Settings()
    {
        //How to call "GetUserData" from here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Short answer: you don't call action methods in other controllers. Longer answer: Split out the shared logic into it's own class.

Answer (score 0):

**Do not** do this. The private method should be in your business logic layer.

---

But if you wanna do it necessarily, make these changes

In the first controller, make the function signature public

```
public UserModel GetUserData(string id)
```

In the second controller, add this namespace.

```
using My.Project.Controllers;
```

Now inside the method write this.

```
public ActionResult Settings(string id)
{
    var controller = new FirstController(); //argh
    var result = controller.GetUserData(id);
}
```